# DDE Topic in VB.NET

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net, plc, dde

I have a VBA code in Excel which connects to a Rockwell PLC and collects data from PLC tag database.I defined a DDE topic in RSlinx Classic a software tool that comes with Rockwell software package and In the Excel Macro i have the following code

```
Private Function OpenRSLinx()
On Error Resume Next
'Open the connection to RSLinx
OpenRSLinx = DDEInitiate("RSLinx", "PLC")

'Check if the connection was made
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error Connecting to topic", vbExclamation, "Error"
    OpenRSLinx = 0
End If

End Function

Sub Check()  " This is my macro"
rslinx = OpenRSLinx()

Value = DDERequest(rslinx, "Tagname.Value")
```

The code works perfectly so i was thinking about making it a VB.NET application but read that DDE topic is not supported on VB.NET.If DDE topic is not supported how can i achieve similar results with VB.Net.I have seen people mentioning about OPC but i don't have any experience with those. Can someone shed some light about a possible solution for my issue.

Comment: https://github.com/anphonic/NDde

Comment: Consider using [OPC](https://www.opcconnect.com/index.php?q=dotnet.php) rather than DDE

Comment: @chris, can you point me to some examples. I googled it and most options I can find are paid solutions.

Comment: @george86 [seen this?](https://github.com/open62541/open62541/wiki/List-of-Open-Source-OPC-UA-Implementations)

Answer (score 1):

You can use AdvancedHMI. It is a .NET application that uses the Visual Studio designer with a VB backend. It includes the drivers to communicate with AB PLCs so you do not need RSLinx. The base package is no cost to use.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VuQCGCNC-q4

Answer (score 1):

Rockwell Technote 46912 has OPC VB.NET Samples.
That is the answer to your question.

Comment: Please provide any relevant documentation such as link to a valid source, etc.

Comment: Here is the link, it does require TechConnect level: https://rockwellautomation.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/46912